# Inline code with R Markdown and Latex throwing unexpected symbol error

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, inline

I'm at a complete loss with this.
The r markdown code throws 'unexpected symbol' error.
Have tried without `$` signs, though read they are a requirement when using markdown with Latex. Have tried `r dim[1]`.
Have tried a number of other solutions I've found but I just can't get past the error.

The dataset contains `r dim[1]` records.

R version 4.0.3, RStudio. LaTeX, output:
pdf_document:
latex_engine: xelatex

Code below:

```
output: pdf_document: latex_engine: xelatex toc: true toc_depth: 2 number_sections: true df_print: kable fig_width: 7 fig_height: 6 fig_caption: true geometry: margin=1in header-includes:

- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Avenir Light} # GFS Didot
\setsansfont{Raleway}
\newpage

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

# Load Libraries
library(rio) # multiple format file import
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra) 
library(pander)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)

install_formats()

# Load Datasets
transcodeData <- rio::import("Data/transcoding_mesurment.tsv", format = "tsv")
youtubeData <- rio::import("Data/youtube_videos.tsv", format = "tsv")

# View DF Heads
options(knitr.kable.NA = "**") 

pander(head(transcodeData), caption= "Video Transcode Specifications\n")
# View structure
# str(transcodeData)
dim <- dim(transcodeData)
dim[2]

noVideos <- length(unique(transcodeData[,"id"]))
```

The dataset contains `r dim[1]` records.

The table presents the data for r noVideos videos of varying formats and corresponding output data to different formats.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible code to debug the error?

Comment: Shared below, thanks Ronak

Comment: That is the place to write answers. You should edit your post to include your code and delete the post below.